# save file without using save file dialog

Tags: c#

I am working on this project still and I am running into a problem. Well here is what I need to do.

> When the user clicks the “Save” button, write the selected record to
>   the file specified in txtFilePath (absolute path not relative) without
>   truncating the values currently inside and handle any exceptions that arise.

Ok here is my code:

```
 private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filePath = txtFilePath.Text;

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath);
            fs.Close();
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                foreach (string line in employeeList.Items)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
            }
```

Now when I go onto my program and want to save something from the employeelist.text that its not being saved to the place I am saving it at. I don;t know if I am missing something in my code or what but it will not save. Here is an example:

> I add a person name to this list in employeelist and in the textbox I
>   have a file called C:\employess\employeelist.txt I want to save it to.
>   I click the save button then I go to that employeelist and it is not
>   being saved.

I don't know what I am doing wrong I have been looking online for a solution but I haven't found anything yet. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to double-check:

- Make sure you don't have the employeelist.txt file open when you're testing
- Make sure you don't have invalid characters in your file name
- Make sure your application has permission to save the file to the location you specified
- Use the debugger to step-through your code and look for swallowed exceptions -- there *must* be a reason the file is not created.
- Check that your `Save_Click` event is wired up to your button -- is the code in your example even running?

Once you check those things, you may want to follow this example for the create vs. append requirement of your project:

```
string path = txtFilePath.Text;

// This text is added only once to the file.
if (!File.Exists(path)) 
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
    {
        foreach (var line in employeeList.Items)
            sw.WriteLine(line.ToString());
    }   
} 
else 
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
    {
        foreach (var line in employeeList.Items)
            sw.WriteLine(line.ToString());
    }
}
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist, or append to it if it does.

Comment: Looks like you're solving a problem @shan doesn't have. He didn't ask how to append if the file already exists. His file is not created at all, and that is the problem

Comment: @Shedal He does indeed ask to append to the file... "without truncating the values currently inside"

Comment: @Rudu But that's not the problem he's stuck on. That's not what he asks us to help him with.

Comment: Yeah, I jumped the gun. There's no reason why his file shouldn't be getting created though, as his logic is sound. There must be an exception getting swallowed, or OP doesn't know how to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Checking that the file exists and then creating it is a bit unnecessary as this can all be handled by the StreamWriter/FileStream parts.  So your above function can be simplified into the following:

```
public void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter file = 
      new StreamWriter(txtFilePath.Text, true);//Open and append
    foreach (object item in employeeList.Items) {
       file.WriteLine(item.toString());
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

[Updated]

What are the types of `txtFilePath` and `employeeList` the former suggests it's a text box, the later suggests it's bound to a non-GUI element perhaps? (WAG)

You might also want to append a blank line at the end so that on further saves you can tell it was an append rather than one long list (depending on your needs of course)

Comment: FileStream's `Dispose()` method will be called, due to the `using` directive in shan's code. So the stream **will** be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with .Net Framework 4 you can do it like this:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        File.AppendAllLines(txtFilePath.Text, employeeList.Items);
}
```

Of course, you probably would want to add a check to have a valid path and a valid enumeration of strings.

Answer (score -1):

If the path looks like a relative one (i.e. doesn't begin with a drive letter), then it will be interpreted that way.

- If you put a full path in the text box, does the file get saved in the proper place?  If so, perhaps this is what was intended.
- If the user doesn't put in a full path, do you have a way to make it one (for example, just sticking C:\ at the beginning)?  Or at least can you tell when there isn't a full path, and reject the request?

Comment: The OP says the path is C:\employess\employeelist.txt in the question.

Comment: Well it doesnt matter where the user wants to save it at it can be saved to and E drive that is up to the user.And the path is suppose to be a absolute path and not a relative one. But the path is what the user wants it to be. If that makes any sense to you.

Comment: well the path of C:\employess\employeelist.txt does exist.